# Submit Authorize.net payment without the CVV

Tags: php, api, authorize.net, merchant-account

I am trying to submit a payment without the CVV number using the AIM API. I am able to submit the payment, but when the charge occurs, it says the CVV number does not match ("No Match") in the Merchant Interface even though I am not submitting a value other than NULL. If I submit the same payment through Authorize.net's Merchant Interface, it will say "Not Applicable". Is there away to accomplish this through the API?

Thanks

Method 1:

```
$payment->setTransaction($credit_card_number, $expiration, $total);
```

Method 2:

```
$payment->setTransaction($credit_card_number, $expiration, $total, NULL, $invoice, $tax);
```

Comment: Can you post a sample payload?

Comment: Don't send anything, haven't worked with the api in a while but you don't even reference it in the xml if you aren't sending it.

Comment: @JohnConde I just updated my original post

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can tell from that code snippet that you are using the [AuthnetAIM class that I wrote](http://www.johnconde.net/blog/tutorial-integrating-the-authorizenet-aim-api-with-php/). To make it so this class never sends over the CVV parameter when it is `null` change this line:

```
$this->params['x_card_code'] = str_pad((int) $cvv, 3, "0", STR_PAD_LEFT);
```

to this:

```
if (!is_null($cvv))
{
    $this->params['x_card_code'] = str_pad((int) $cvv, 3, "0", STR_PAD_LEFT);
}
```